# django-daguerre don't work after deployment

Tags: django

I'm using daguerre to display images on my site and it works nice on the development server

```
{% load daguerre %}

<div class = "col-sm-4">
    <img class = "img-thumbnail" src="{% adjust product.images.first.src 'fill' width=250 height=300%}" />
</div>
<div class = "col-sm-1" id = "mini-thumbs">
{% for img in product.images.rest %}
    <img class = "img-thumbnail" src="{% adjust img.src 'fill' width=80 height=100 %}" />
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

but it's not working after deployment on vps server, src attribute is empty.

And yet daguerre tables in postgres DB(daguerre_adjustedimage, daguerre_area) have no records. The rest functional is working fine except daguerre. Can you suggest me what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to install PIL prerequisites on my vps server:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev
```

and reinstall Pillow after that:

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow
```